# Vue.js computed property to update quantity

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have a simple shopping cart app, and I have it so that the user can add items to the cart and then remove them (using a `@click` event). The problem I am facing is that I cannot figure out how to update the quantity in my `Product` after I remove an item from the `Cart`. Here is the relevant part from my `index.html`:

```
<span v-for="item in items">
    <h3>Product</h3>
    Item: {{item.name}}<br>
    Price: {{item.price}}<br>
    Quantity: {{inStock > 0 ? inStock : 'Out of Stock'}}<br>
    <button
      class="btn btn-primary"
      :disabled="inStock===0"
      @click="addToCart(item)">
          Add to Cart
    </button>
</span>
```

Here is a fiddle containing the `Vue` instance: https://jsfiddle.net/Amidi/yzwrzugz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could increase the `item.stock` value into the `remove` method:

```
remove: function (item) {
  this.itemInCart.splice(item, 1)
  var updateStock = this.items[0].stock
  item.stock++
  this.restock.push(updateStock)
}
```